# Admin setting js minify option is not working

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.1.4, minify

I have enabled the option **minify js file** in admin panel setting. But after doing these, it doesn't minify any single js file. It has just changed the name of js file to the `.min.js` and only in webpage. Even if you check file name in FTP it's still name as `.js` without `.min`. Not understanding this Option in magento 2. How it works?

Comment: Did you use the CDN or any other network delivery system?

Comment: No.. i don't use CDN all JS are in FTP only

Answer (score 0):

You have run this command after setting the minify js option to yes.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This will create minified js files.